# Windows Server 2008 R2: upload limit

Tags: windows-server-2008, uploading

i'm running php on my win 2008 r2 server and i'm experiencing problems when uploading files bigger than 1MB. i've already checked the limits in my php.ini - and restarted the server but it didn't help.

these are my values:

```
post_max_size 128M 
upload_max_filesize 128M
```

any ideas which could still be wrong?

thanks

Comment: What are the values in php.ini? Have you looked at `phpinfo()` to see if they are indeed in effect?

Comment: yes i've got these values:
post_max_size 128M 
upload_max_filesize 128M 
uploading simply stops after 1mb without any error .. :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue a while ago, only applies if you use IIS7+ thou (haven't tested with previous versions):

- Open **IIS manager**
- **Select the website** for which bigger uploads should be available
- Double click the **request filtering** icon, you should see a screen with some tabs
- **Right click** in a tab and select **edit feature settings**
- Adjust the **Maximum allowed content length** (bytes) field

That did the trick for me